# My counter for subsections starts with 3, but then increases by 3 each time, and i need it to increase by 1

Tags: counters, subsection

My counter for subsections starts with 3, but then increases by 3 each time, and i need it to increase by 1
I can see where is the error, but i cant find the other way to start the counter with 3

```
\renewcommand{\subsection}[1]{
    \addtocounter{subsection}{3}
    \Large{
        ~
        
        \textbf{\Large{\thesubsection. #1}}
        
        ~
    }
```

Which gives me following:

1.3. Sample Text

1.6. Sample Text

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  You've done this yourself: `\addtocounter{subsection}{3}` does exactly what it says.  You don't say what document class you're using, but most classes include `\stepcounter`, which adds 1 at every use.

Comment: You have a fundamental problem here. You're redefining something that works already as expected. I guess your main question here should be how do you redefine the *formatting* of the `\subsection`s, rather than redefining the internals of `\subsection`...?

Comment: @barbarabeeton 
Document class is article.
Yeah, sorry for misunderstanding, \addtocounter is indeed works as expected, i just do not understand how can i use \stepcounter command to receive the following:
1.3 Sample Text
1.4 Sample Text

Comment: do not use stepcounter, section numbers are incremented automatically `\Large`  does not take an argument so do not use `{` in `\Large{` but do not `\renewcommand{\subsection}` this is breaking all latex section handling

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to do.  But have you tried `\setcounter{subsection}{2}` just before the `\subsection` that you want to be 1.3?

Comment: what is the actual question as having subsections numbered 1.1, 1.2,1.3,... is the default behaviour

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear but it appears you want section 1 with subsections starting 1.3, so

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\section{aaa}

\setcounter{subsection}{2}
\subsection{abc abc}
xxx
\subsection{abc abc}
xxx
\subsection{abc abc}
xxx

\end{document}
```